# issue in export of apex class from data loader

Tags: apex

I have a few questions related to exporting the data in data loader.

1. Does sobject type support in tabsettings?
2. what is the sobjecttype for export the apex class from the profile using data loader.eg:sobject type for object permission =ObjectPermsission from profile
         sobject type for Apex class = ??

It does not take the sobject type for Apex class as apex class from profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't export Apex code with Data Loader. Apex, Visualforce and Lightning are all metadata and cannot be exported with data export tools.

Comment: Thanks @David Cheng

Answer (score 1):

The Metadata API must be used to extract the information you need:

-Tabs can be extracted as CustomTab metadata, and related configuration can be located in Profiles or Permission Sets as tabVisibilities, and can also be located in CustomApplication metadata as available tabs

-Apex code can be extracted as ApexClass or ApexTrigger metadata types

To export metadata from an org, you can use a tool such as Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) and use a package.xml manifest that specifies ApexClass and CustomTab as elements within. You can produce a package manifest from following the details in (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm) or by using an automatic package builder such as (https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/)